# How to change cursor on disabled buttons in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I just started working on C# with Visual Studio & Windows Forms Applications. I was trying to create a Calculator and I was wondering if I could change the cursor type on a button which is disabled, I can't figure out how to do it, please help me thank you!

Edit: here's the code I tried to do, it only works if the button's enabled...

```
private void txt_current_operation_MouseHover(object sender,EventArgs e) {

            txt_current_operation.Cursor=Cursors.Hand;
        }
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hack Answer*

Assuming the Button is contained by the Form, you can handle the MouseMove event of the Form and change the cursor from there:

```
private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle rc = txt_current_operation.RectangleToScreen(txt_current_operation.ClientRectangle);
    this.Cursor = rc.Contains(Cursor.Position) ? Cursors.Hand : Cursors.Default;
}
```

If the Button was contained by a Panel, or some other container besides the Form, then you'd change to the MouseMove event of that container instead.

Demonstration:

[image]

Comment: @Face I am glad to hear that. If the answer can solve your problem, you can click '✔' to mark the reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.